# How do I add an activity under com.X.X in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I received a project from someone and was tasked to add some feautres. I wanted to add an activity under com.X.X . However, there was no such selection for me. Selecting `New > File` only gives me a blank .java file. There wasn't a selection for me to choose a blank activity, activity with button, etc. How do I fix it? My API level is on 23.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please send a full screenshot of the android studio. Maybe the project Gradle is not generated that's why it displays errors on every java file.

Comment: please check your gradle and build again....you gradle may not have sync properly...

Comment: @PratikSatani https://imgur.com/a/ndoyqmc

Comment: You need to re-sync project after checking gradle files, also make sure your module is selected change the "Add configuration" to "app". Try to build the project and if it fails, please do share the logs

Comment: Yes, I am correct. Go to the File menu and select sync project with Gradle file.

Comment: alright! that works! thanks a lot!

Comment: which was worked?

Comment: syncing project with gradle files

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to sync the project. Go to the File menu and select sync project with Gradle file. Then you will get all the options in the File menu.

Happy coding...